# Android MediaPlayer Internal subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, libvlc, subtitle

I need to show internal subtitles with android MediaPlayer. 
I am playing a .ts stream, subtitles are coming on a seperate stream with DVB sub codec.
Currently working on Android 4.2.2, DVB sub is not supported with native media player.
Any Alternative?

Comment: it's not supported in native player, you have to look for an external library to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at Google's open source video player https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

They don't have DVB, but you can either add your own parser or if you already have it somewhere, then just plug it to the player.

Otherwise, if you want to do it with MediaPlayer, then you need to keep track of current playback time and display the subtitles on top in a separate view.